# Neither using VBA .Find nor Application.Match to match dates in an Excel Range find the date

Tags: excel, date, calendar, match, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that will take a list of dates, and find those dates on a different sheet and populate some info in the cell below the matching date.   The data to search through looks something like this:
`ROW23:  dates generated by formula (formatted: d-mmm)
ROW24: Mix of empty cells and cells with text and numbers.
ROW25:  dates generated by formula (formatted: d-mmm)
ROW26:  Mix of empty cells and cells with text and numbers.
and so on`
This range is called "Calendar" and is Sheet9(B23:O74).
This list of dates to search are "List_Holidays" and is Sheet5(B9:B12,B16:B21).  Once the date is located, the text to return in the cell below it is "List_HolAbbr" on Sheet5(A9:A12,A16:A21).

Currently I'm stuck on stage 1 of this code:  Get it to run looking for only one date.
Stage 2 is to have it search for a list of dates.
Stage 3 is to have it only search through the rows that actually contain dates from the example above (skip the row of empty cells and cells with text/#s.
Stage 4:  Have it populate the cell under the found date with some text.

My attempt so far:

```
Sub holidays()
Dim Cal As Range
Dim vholidays As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim clgcaldate As Range
Set Cal = Sheets("2015_Consolidated").Range("Calendar")  
'Find this
Set rgholidays = Worksheets("Holidays_EndPeriods").Range("F10")        'This is the date of the holiday to find in range Calendar  
vholidays = DateValue(rgholidays)
MsgBox "vholidays is " & vholidays  
'Search this range
MsgBox "g47 is: " & Sheets("2015_Consolidated").Cells(47, "G")  'G47 is the match to the cell in "rgholidays".
 For Each cl In Cal
    'With Range("List_Holidays)
    Set rFound = Cells.Find(what:=vholidays, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)             'The cell in range Calendar that matches to vholidays  
'Match found
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "rFound is " & rFound
    End If
    'End With
    Next cl
MsgBox "vholidays is " & vholidays & " and is located: " & rFound
End Sub`
```

The first 2 `msgbox`s are correct, but it does not find the match in G47.

I also tried this code, found at: [Excel VBA - Using Find method on a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448379/excel-vba-using-find-method-on-a-range-of-dates)
Second try, using the same variables as above.

```
`MsgBox "vhol is " & vholidays & "   rghol is " & rgholidays  
For Each cl In Cal
    With rgholidays
        Set rFound = .Find(vholidays, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox cell
        End If
    End With
Next cl
End Sub`
```

Again, this does not return a match.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm recommends using `DateValue()` to convert the dates to a serial number, which seems reasonable to me and i tried it in the first example.

I've found some other references, but those are further removed from I'm trying to do.
Any suggestions to make this work?

Edit:  I set a condition to test if the formats were the same for the search value and the value it should find.  It said they were the same.
Testing the find/replace gui box on the spreadsheet, "find" does not locate the proper cell regardless of the find/replace settings.

Edit:  I tried Application.Match.  No match found.  This loops through each column in the range looking for a match to the date, but doesn't find anything.

```
Sub holidays()

Dim Calendar As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim rFound As Variant
Dim findthis As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim Cal As Range

Set Cal = Sheets("2015_Consolidated").Range("Calendar")
findthis = CDate(CLng(Sheets("2015_Consolidated").Range("K17")))    '"1/13/2015"
Debug.Print "find this:" & findthis
Debug.Print "cell d23: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(23, 4)
For Each rng In Range("Calendar").Columns
  Debug.Print rng.Address
  rFound = Application.Match(findthis, rng.Address, 0)

  If IsError(rFound) Then
    Debug.Print "Not found"
  Else
    Debug.Print rFound
  End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Afer you set "Cal" and "rgholidays" variables in your code, try:

```
For each cell in Cal
  if format(rgholidays,"m/d/yyyy")=format(cell,"m/d/yyyy") then
      'Cell has the same date, do some code
  endif
Next cell
```

When working with dates, another way to work with them is to format them yyyymmdd, then the larger numbers are always later then smaller ones, for example. This should get stage 1 of your question, to find the dates. Stage 2 and 4 should be some version of this code, combined with something you write. Stage 3 might be tricky, unless your line of non-dates is always constant.

Comment: For "cell", do you mean my variable "cl"?

Comment: Tried it.  It still doesn't find it.  I set a condition to test if the formats were the same for the search value and the value it should find.  It said they were the same.

Comment: By not find it do you mean code you wrote in place of the comment "do some code" did not run, or something different?

Comment: My code didn't find a match by adding in your suggestion.